# Create a function which replaces a mysql value if it isn't empty?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two keys in the database called `background-video-length`and `slide_duration`. The one called `background-video-length`is not always set, when it is not, it is `NULL`. If it is anything but `NULL` I want to transfer the value from `background-video-length` to `slide_duration`and replace whatever is set in this one.
And another thing, `slide_duration`isn't always there, when it is empty it is removed, so it must be created if `background-video-length` value contains anything. If `background-video-length` is `NULL` I want to delete `slide_duration` if it doesn't contain anything previously.

EDIT:
I have this code to set the `background-video-length` in the database:

```
  $attachment_id = attachment_url_to_postid( $_POST[ 'background-video' ] );
  $video_meta = get_post_meta( $attachment_id , '_wp_attachment_metadata', true );
if( isset( $_POST[ 'background-video' ] ) ) {
  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'background-video-length', $video_meta['length'] ); 
}
```

Comment: Where is Your code?

Comment: Sounds like an interesting project. Let us know if you have any specific code issues - we're not here to write code for you.